# Pyramid Pattern in shell scripting : In for((j=1; j<=2*i - 1; j++)) this line, I got error of operand expected (error token is "<=")?

Tags: shell

```
for((i=1; i<=rows; i++))
do
  for((j=1; j<=rows - i; j++))
  do
    echo -n "  "
  done
  for((j=1; j<=2*i - 1; j++))
  do
    echo -n "* "
  done
  echo
done
```

In `for((j=1; j<=2*i - 1; j++))` this line, i got error of operand expected (error token is "<=")

Comment: Which shell, specifically? This is syntax that only works in extended shells; it won't work in `sh`. (It's also bad form to not put spaces between words; in this case, between `for` and `((`; but that won't necessarily cause problems).

Comment: See your code working fine when run with bash at https://ideone.com/ErUIwP

Comment: BTW, if you want broad compatibility, it's also best to replace `echo -n foo` with `printf %s foo`. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html